# How to compare two fields in two tables in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, compare

Table_1

```
ID | Username
 1   John
 2   Mike
 3   Chase
 4   Shane
```

Table_2

```
 ID | Username
 1  | John
 2  | Kenny
 3  | Chase
 4  | Shane
```

I want to get **ID** from **Table_1**. Then find that **ID** in **table_2**. Then i need it to look at the field **Username** in both tables. and if they match do nothing, If they don't match then update it to the username in **Table_2** and run some code (like email me)

I need to to check every row in Table_1 everytime I run the script.

Comment: Have you tried to write something? Can you show us?

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use INNER JOIN in case to find the matching ID in both the tables and if you got one then update.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT table_1.id as id_one,table_1.name as name_one,table_2.name as name_two FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON (table_1.id = table_2.id)") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
    {
         while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
         {
               if($fetch['name_one'] != $fetch['name_two'])
               {
                     // UPDATE table_1 'name' FIELD

                       mysql_query("UPDATE table_1 SET name = '".$fetch['name_two']."' WHERE id = ".$fetch['id_one']) or die(mysql_error());

                          // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT
               }

         }
    }
```

Comment: The old mysql functions are deprecated.  Use of the new PDO library is recommended.

Comment: this worked, but mysql is deprecated so im using mysqli instead, thanks for you answer, besides changing mysql to mysqli it worked like a dream.  thanks again and have a good day.

Comment: Cully thanx for the advice.

And the user it ws my pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

My MySQL is a little rusty, but it can be done with a single Update statement. The following should update the usernames in Table_1 only where they differ from Table_2. You may have to tweak the syntax a little...

```
update Table_1 t1
join  Table_2 t2
   on  t2.id = t1.id
  and  t2.Username <> t1.Username
set   t1.Username = t2.Username;
```

You can query beforehand to generate any email you need.